# In Openfire, how can I get who have subscribed a node?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe

Some client subscribe a node, I want to know how to get the subscriber.

Is there some plugins in the Openfire can do this?

Comment: Can you explain a little more exactly what you want?  You mentioned a plugin, so that would assume you are looking for this information on the server.  Are you looking to OK pending subscribers ...?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build the smack version from the repo to get PubSub support. See my [blog](http://oneminutedistraction.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/xmpp-pubsub/) for details. Once you have build smack, this is how you retrieve the list of subscribers

```
//Assume pubsub jid is pubsub.myserver
PubSubManager mgr = new PubSubManager(conn, "pubsub.myserver");

//Assume we are dealing with leafnode
LeafNode node = (LeafNode)mgr.getNode("mynode");

List<Subscriptions> subscriptions = node.getSubscriptions();
```

Comment: Nightly builds are now available at http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/nightly_smack.jsp